# How can I use INSERT INTO using knex and typescrypt

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js

First this is my table structure:

```
create table recipes
(
    id varchar(255) primary key not null,
    tittle varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(300) not null,
    user_id varchar(255),
    creation_date datetime default current_timestamp,
    foreign key(user_id) references users(id)
);
```

As you can see my creation_date has a default, so I don't have to send this info, and I'm using knex.js in node with Typescript, and I'm trying to reproduce this command:

```
insert into recipes (id, tittle, description, user_id) 
values ("001", "rosquinha", "sdfsdfsdfsddf", "28356b2b-5d20-4a87-b2f7-1a63c84a2351");
```

To do that, in my code I'm trying this:

```
export class RecipesDataBase extends BaseDataBase {
    public async createRecipe(recipe: Recipes) {
        try {
            await BaseDataBase.connection("recipes").insert({
                id: recipe.getId(),
                tittle: recipe.getTittle(),
                description: recipe.getDescription(),
                user_id: recipe.getUserId(),
            })
        } catch (error:any) {
            throw new Error(error)
        }
    }
}
```

but it's not working, I think that is because I'm not choosing what columns I want to send, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you have some error log?

Comment: Unfortunately, don't.